# All phrases, proverbs, parables, epigrams are adages?

Tags: grammar, vocabulary, hypernyms

Is it safe to assume what I just asked?

Like **Adage** is the superset that constitutes of all these things?

Or are there any exceptions?

Comment: An adage, by definition, is short. Parables aren't. I'd consider adage more of a synonym of most of the things you mentioned than a hypernym for all of them.

Comment: A "phrase" could be something as simple as "in the house".  And the difference between the rest is pretty vaguely defined.

Comment: Because of its etymology, I don't use "adage", unless the saying is old.

Comment: @HotLicks You have eliminated "phrases" as too general, and epigrams are terse. As for "adage,"  The Cambridge Online Dictionary offers " a wise saying:
He remembered the OLD adage "Look before you leap".
Synonym
proverb.
 Here are some  statements from other sources: 1) "a short popular saying, usually of unknown and ancient origin,...2) A saying that sets forth a general truth and that has gained credit through long use. 3) a traditional saying expressing... " I think I'm on the side of this battle that lost, and  have just lucked out because most, but not all,  adages are old.

Comment: Similar: [What is the difference between a proverb, an adage, and an aphorism?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/73199)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try [Wordnet](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu). Search each word, click the 'S' link and expand the 'direct hypernym' link. That'll show what type of word each one is. Eg, it shows that both epigram and proverb are a type of 'saying, expression, locution' while parable is a type of 'story'. I've no idea how well regarded Wordnet is but hope this helps.