# Is there such a thing as a new adage?

Tags: etymology, popular-refrains, proverbs

I was brought up to understand that a proverb that is described as an adage is, by virtue of its longevity, old.  Take, for exapmle, the Old Testament book of Proverbs, some of which date back thousands of years:

> A gentle answer turns away wrath, but a harsh word stirs up anger.

I found an interesting 2018 question on the origin of a particular proverb:
[Origin of “the apple doesn’t fall far from the tree”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/457206/origin-of-the-apple-doesn-t-fall-far-from-the-tree)

I am more concerned about how old an adage needs to be before it can be accepted as an adage.

Are there any examples of new adages that have come into recent circulation?

Comment: There's no age requirement; [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/adage) defines an adage as "a saying often in metaphorical form that typically embodies a common observation". Generally an adage is expected to be well-known, but that's not an invariable requirement, and it could be something that an individual uses as a guiding principle ([as here](https://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2023/sep/13/keir-starmer-voters-labour-leader-opposition)).

Comment: @StuartF - unable to access that link but thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are willing to accept the thesis that a "proverb" is as liable to be old as an "adage," you may be interested in the collection of sayings compiled in Charles Doyle, Wolfgang Mieder, and Fred Shapiro, eds., *The [Yale] Dictionary of Modern Proverbs* (2012), which consists entirely of "proverbs" that the researchers could trace no farther back than 1900.

In the introduction to this dictionary, the editors write:

> A frequently used synonym for the word *proverb* in sixteenth-century England was "old said saw." While rightly acknowledging the fundamentally *oral* character of proverbs (in fact, *said* and *saw* are cognate "saying" words), the phrase "old said saw" also voices the common impression that proverbs, by their nature, must be *old* expressions, somehow encapsulating the venerable wisdom of long-ago times. The very concept of a *modern proverb*, then, must seem anomalous or paradoxical.
>
> However, there must have existed a time when even an "old said saw" was a *new* said saw! Like other kinds of folklore, and like words themselves, new proverbs are continually being fashioned or "coined" (while others lapse into obsolescence). Such is the nature of human creativity as expressed in oral tradition, where proverbs exist before someone thinks to write them down.

The editors go on to remark that "folklorists know that new proverbs continually arise"—and their book, which uses the "historical principles" approach to seeking earliest recorded uses, provides numerous examples of proverbs that I would have imagined were many years older than the earliest instance that Yale researchers have identified for them. Here is a selection of modern proverbs from the dictionary, with the year of first confirmed occurrence noted in parentheses after the saying:

> The customer is always right. (1905)
>
> Better to light one candle than to curse the darkness. (1907)
>
> You win some, you lose some. (1912)
>
> A rising tide lifts all boats. (1915)
>
> The blacker the berry, the sweeter the juice. (1929)
>
> The glass is either half empty or half full. (1930)
>
> If you can't stand the heat, get out of the kitchen. (1931)
>
> You can't fight city hall. (1934)
>
> Don't make waves. (1934)
>
> Time flies when you're having fun. (1939)
>
> It's better to be lucky than good. (1939)
>
> It's a jungle out there. (1951)
>
> Stop and smell the roses. (1951)
>
> Don't get mad, get even. (1956)
>
> Get your ducks in a row. (1956)
>
> Age is just a number. (1957)
>
> Don't do the crime if you can't do the time. (1957)
>
> If it ain't broke, don't fix it. (1960)
>
> What goes around comes around. (1961)
>
> The devil is in the details (1963)
>
> The game isn't over until the last man is out. (1965)
>
> It is easier to ask forgiveness than permission. (1966)
>
> The nail that sticks out gets hammered down. (1969)
>
> Today is the first day of the rest of your life. (1969)
>
> Don't try to reinvent the wheel. (1970)
>
> Keep your friends close but your enemies closer. (1974)
>
> You have to kiss a lot of frogs to find a prince. (1976)
>
> You are only as good as your last mistake. (1979)
>
> It takes a village to raise a child. (1981)
>
> You booze, you lose. (1986)
>
> Never bring a knife to a gunfight. (1988)
>
> You cannot herd cats. (1992)
>
> The second mouse gets the cheese. (1997)

It seems to me that virtually every one of these "modern proverbs" could be characterized as an adage—and many of them are not particularly old. It would therefore seem reasonable to conclude that there are indeed new adages (relatively speaking), including ones that we probably haven't yet recognized for what they are. Nevertheless, I would argue that an adage should demonstrate some evidence of staying power if it is to be distinguished from a mere catchphrase, which may enjoy a season or a year or two of vogue and then fade away.

Comment: Outstanding! Appreciate the examples of modern proverbs and the dates attributed to them.  Thanks for cheering me up and for teaching me something new.

Answer (score 3):

Most of the online dictionary definitions give no age requirement, and in fact many of them add 'old' to their example *"…the old adage…"* to illustrate their point.

Apple built-in dictionary

> **adage | ˈadɪdʒ |**
> noun
> a proverb or short statement expressing a general truth: *the old adage ‘out of sight out of mind’.*

An example of a new adage might be…

> Any data stored in fewer than three distinct locations ought to be considered temporary.

Might not be as pithy, but it's just as 'true'.

> There's no such thing as a free lunch

and

> Shit happens

are both 20th century; the first from maybe the 20s/30s [although popularised later by Robert Heinlein as "There ain't no such thing as a free lunch" [TANSTAAFL], the second from the 60s.

Comment: What distinguishes a modern adage from a rule of thumb? Pithiness?

Comment: no-one mentioned 'rule of thumb' which is an approximation, a general guide following observations, not an adage/proverb/aphorism… If you want distinctions, see https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/73199/what-are-the-differences-between-a-proverb-adage-aphorism-epigram-maxim-and

Comment: No one mentioned rules of thumb, but "Any data stored in fewer than three distinct locations ought to be considered temporary" seems like one.

Comment: What makes you think that? This is sound & standard backup strategy, known as 123. Put the only copy of any data on a USB stick & you have an accident waiting to [rather rapidly] happen. Put two copies on two hard drives & keep them in the same building, then you're fine unless there's a fire, flood, earthquake… Three copies, at least one of which is off-site, then you're in with a chance.

Comment: A more accurate version I’ve often heard is, “All data is temporary; only data loss is permanent”.

Comment: The expression, "All data is temproary; only data loss is permanent" sound like a description of my brain.  Hope the Moderators don't jump in to rebuke us for humour.